# Generating Random ID's in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to create a table in sql server and fill it up with data (people's info) every person should have a unique ID different than the auto incremented ID's by sql server 
For example i need the ID for the first person inserted like this: 2016xxxx
how to fix the 2016 and randomly generate the numbers after that to be filled instead of xxxx
should i use a regular expression ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate random number for each row in a TSQL Select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select)

Comment: Why not just use a sequential `identity` id?

Comment: and when the year is 2017 I guess you want this number to be 2017?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid exactly i want to increment it by the year we are in, but now my question is how to do so ? 
i have a deadline to make it and it must work

Comment: @GordonLinoff i tried but it didn't work

Comment: @RB. didn't find my answer there !!

Comment: When you followed the link above, exactly how did it "not work"? If you want to reach your deadline you need to make some kind of effort.

Comment: The answer on how to generate a random number is in there. You need a random number between 0 and 9999... The linked answer shows you how: `ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 10000`. Add `20160000` to it and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create a computed column like below

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
    PkAutoId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    PersonUniqueNo AS (CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + RIGHT(RIGHT(CAST(RAND() AS VARCHAR),4) + CAST(PkAutoId AS VARCHAR),4))
)
```

Computed Column "PersonUniqueNo" is 8 Digit Unique Number comprising of Current Year And Conceited value of Random number and Primary Key Id for 4 Length, Total length will be 8 as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that would get the next value for you and use that instead of an AUTO_INCREMENT field.

I wouldn't recommend it tho. You shouldn't format the data like that before inserting it. That sort of thing should be done on the way out, preferably by the front-end code. Or you can just write a query and create a view ...
However if you must do that here is the complete answer with the code:
 [Is there a way to insert an auto-incremental primary id with a prefix in mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405896/is-there-a-way-to-insert-an-auto-incremental-primary-id-with-a-prefix-in-mysql-d)

Comment: That's for MySQL but yes, your advice is sound - it's not a good idea to do that.