# Create an ID field with date concatenated in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I need create an id field for an table.
That id field needs to be in this format "idnumber.month.year" (idnumber.month.year), 
for example:

*Actual month*:

- First insert of month generates that `id=01.10.2013`
- Second insert of month generates that `id=02.10.2013`

*Next month*

- autocreates that `id=01.11.2013`

*Next month*

- autocreates that `id=01.12.2013`

*Next year*

- autocreates that `id=01.01.2014`

My question is: Is there a "MySQL way" to solve this? or, how can I automate that with PHP/mysql?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this combined id field?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible to do automatically in mySQL. Either way, you should keep an additional auto-increment numeric ID next to this

Comment: Yeas @Pekka웃, but i dont know how controll the AI field to restart after month/year over

Comment: You'll have to do this in PHP. Look for the highest field with the current month name, and make the next one that +1. There is the potential for collisions, though, when two scripts try to insert data at the same time. THat's why auto-increment IDs are the easiest way to go.... what exactly is this going to be used for? THere may be a better way to do this.

Comment: protocol number of generated docs by system.

Comment: Don't use auto_increment for this.

Comment: yeah, i dont do... I can't imagine how can use AI field.

Answer (score 1):

Could you create a trigger before insert, review this [Create insert trigger to auto increment int field of composite PK (String, int), restart numbering at 1 for new Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618139/create-insert-trigger-to-auto-increment-int-field-of-composite-pk-string-int) perhaps is your solution